# Show History in Eclipse shows nothing

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm trying to figure out why Eclipse (v3.5.1) does not show any CVS history information when I use the Team->Show History context menu on a file. "Show Annotation" does show the annotations correctly, so I know the connection to my CVS server is working correctly. With Show History I just get the History tab with three panes, but nothing in them. Strangely Show History has worked in the past.

I've tried googling around for information on this issue, but no one seems to have the same problem. I also tried launching Eclipse in debug mode (./eclipse -debug) but I get no relevant error messages. I ran Eclipse in clean mode as well to clear out any cached plug-in data.

What other methods are out there for troubleshooting Eclipse and its integration with CVS?

I suspect this might be a rendering issue. If I select Show Annotation, then select an annotation in the editor window, the History tab shows the comment associated with the selected checkin, but nothing else, no versions or branch info. So it seems the information is there, but is not getting drawn by Eclipse. Perhaps an issue with SWT, or GDK?

Comment: Additional info: Running on 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I'm now pretty sure the problem is a graphics rendering problem. Some deeper digging in the eclipse bugbase led to what I think is the issue, which appears to be a bug in SWT:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=274508

It also looks like there is a patch available for Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293551

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in version 3.6 of Eclipse as noted in this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313480

I tried 3.5.2 first, which still had the problem. I then tried 3.6RC4 and was able to verify that the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From mmorrisson's link above (it's just simpler to have it here) :

your .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui/dialog_settings.xml should contain the following instead of value="0" everywhere :

```
<section name="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSHistoryTableProvider">
    <item value="112" key="COL_DATE"/>
    <item value="245" key="COL_COMMENT"/>
    <item value="72" key="COL_TAGS"/>
    <item value="1024" key="SORT_COL_DIRECTION"/>
    <item value="COL_DATE" key="SORT_COL_NAME"/>
    <item value="87" key="COL_REVISIONID"/>
    <item value="70" key="COL_AUTHOR"/>
</section>
```

The .metadata directory is at the root of your workspace.